# "Add Linq-to-SQL Datacontext to Current Project" Disabled in SQL Server Compact

Tags: sqlite, linq-to-sql, sql-server-ce-4, sql-server-ce-toolbox

I'm trying to create Linq-to-sql `DataContext` using SQLite/SQL Server Compact Toolbox but I can't seem to drag the tables to the Linq-to-SQL file. So I tried to right click my table in the toolbox and the "Add Linq-to-SQL Datacontext to current project..." is disabled.

I'm currently using SQL Server CE 4.0, Visual Studio Community 2015 and the SQLite/SQL Server Compact Toolbox extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use this feature, you must also have the SQL Server Compact 3.5 MSI installed. More information and download links here: https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/wiki

Comment: msi? sorry im new to wpf and everything